# Convert map of strings or lists into string of values or comma-separate values

Tags: jq

I have a JSON file:

```json
{
  "foo": "xxx",
  "bar": ["yyy","zzz"]
}
```

I want to use JQ to convert this to:

```text
xxx yyy,zzz
```

I have tried various things and the closest I can get is:

```
▶ cat xx.json | jq -r 'to_entries[] | if (.value | type)=="string" then (.value) else (.value | join(",")) end' 
xxx
yyy,zzz
```

Note that I do not know the names of the keys in the JSON file in advance, and I am relying on the behaviour of `to_entries` to output the entries in order sorted by key (just in case someone is thinking of a way to do this that would result in the output being non-deterministically ordered).

Is there any concise way to do this using a JQ one-liner?

Comment: Your remark about `to_entries` is unclear. Please provide example that would require sorting.

Comment: @oliv On to_entries e.g. https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/561 ? I don't know what you mean by an example that would require sorting. My requirement is that the JQ command sorts them, which to_entries does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
<file jq -r '[.foo,(.bar|join(","))]|join(" ")'
```

It only joins twice the both `.foo` and `.bar` field in order have them in the same line.

---

If you don't know the key names, you could use this:

```
<file jq -r 'to_entries|map(.value|[strings?//.[]]|join(","))|join(" ")'
```

That is close to your solution, except that it uses `strings` builtin function and the operator `//` and `?` to avoid using a `if ... then ...`.

Comment: You have assumed that I know the names of keys however, whereas I don't.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that is agnostic both about the key names and their order, and is fairly robust in other respects:

```
jq -r 'to_entries
  | sort_by(.value|type) 
  | reverse .  # "string" before "array"
  | map(.value | if type == "array" then join(",") else tostring end)
  | join(" ")'
```